# Spherical Graph Layout in Python

Tags: python, graph, 3d

## Objective

- Display a 3D **Sphere** graph structure based on input edges & nodes using VTK for visualisation. As for example shown in https://epfl-lts2.github.io/gspbox-html/doc/graphs/gsp_sphere.html

Target:

[image]

## State of work

- Input data as given factor
- NetworkX for position calculation
- Handover to VTK methods for 3D visualisation

## Problem

3 years ago, I had achieved the visualisation as shown above. Unfortunately, I did a little bit of too much cleaning and I just realized, that I dont have these methods anymore. It is somehow a force-directed graph on a sphere surface. Maybe similar to the "strong gravity" parameter in the 2D forceatlas. I have not found any 3D implementation of this yet.

I tried again with the following algorithms, but none of them has produced this layout, neither have parameter tuning of these algorithms (or did I miss an important one?):

- NetworkX: Spherical, Spring, Shell, Kamada Kawaii, Fruchterman-Reingold (the 2D fruchterman-reingold in Gephi looks like it could come close to the target in a 3D version, yet gephi does not support 3D or did I oversee something?)
- ForceAtlas2
- Gephi (the 2D fruchterman-reingold looks like a circle, but this is not available in 3D, nor does the 3D Force Atlas produce valid Z-Coordinates (they are within a range of +1e-4 and -1e-4)

Researching for "spherical graph layout" has not brought me to any progress (only to this view which seems very similar https://observablehq.com/@fil/3d-graph-on-sphere ).

How can I achieve this spherical layout using python (or a third party which provides a positioning information)

**Update:** I made some progress and found the keywords non-euclidean, hyperbolic and spherical force-directed algorithms, however still not achieved anything yet. Or Non-Euclidean Riemann Embeddings ([https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/~kobourov/riemann_embedders.pdf](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/%7Ekobourov/riemann_embedders.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the python lib version of the GSPBOX?
If yes, why it does not work for you?

https://pygsp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/graphs.html

Comment: Hey @leonardo. Thank you very much for your response. The sphere algorithm from GSPBOX randomly samples points on a sphere surface and connects them by some kind of nearest neighbor and randomness algorithm. In my case, I do have the graph structure (G={V,E}) already but the problem lies within positioning the nodes in a proper distributed way on the sphere surface by a smart algorithm (like those mentioned in my "work so far").